# Square roots of a $3\times3$ matrix

Tags: matrices

Here is  $3\times3$ matrix$$\begin{pmatrix}   1&    -18&    0\\
    0  & 4&   0\\
    -8&   -13  &  9\end{pmatrix}$$
How can I find two different matrices so that $R^2=A$?

Comment: Reduce to RREF first?

Comment: Diagonalise? If $R$ works so does $-R$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Finding a square root is easy for a diagonal matrix. If you can write $A$ as $PDP^{-1}$ with $D$ a diagonal matrix and if $S^2 = D$, then $R=PSP^{-1}$ is a square root of $A$.

> Your matrix is diagonalizable and has eigenvalues $1$, $4$ and $9$.

Comment: Interestingly, the eigenvalues are perfect squares, so this is a well crafted exercise, and your solution is for sure interesting and...doable. I just got myself a nice exercise for my poor hardworking students...+1

Comment: Well they needn't be for this method to work but indeed, this probably isn't a coincidence... :-).

Comment: It's a nice application of diagonalization which I hadn't thought off....

Comment: You're welcome @Ioanah.